# Install jekyll-admin to github pages hosted jekyll site

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

I am having difficulty having jekyll-admin to my github page.

I have github page github.com/kadadi92/lanyon on website novellatranslation.com . As the [plugin readme](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-admin) says, I have included the plugin name to _config.yml file but http://novellatranslation.com/admin link is not working.

It may be a minor problem but I am new to Ruby-Jekyll environment. It will be very helpful if you can give solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jekyll Admin is intended to be run on your localhost for now. We are planning to support running it on Github Pages in the long term. We just need to fix some current issues, make it really secure and implement some useful features for now.

Answer (score 5):

Github pages does not support any additional ruby gems, only the gems [included in the Github Pages gem](https://pages.github.com/versions/). The `jekyll-admin` gem is not included in that list

Comment: So is there any way I can incorporate jekyll-admin to github pages?

Comment: no, you'd have to host the site on a different platform